# Using ffmpeg to apply sepia filter and add title cards to video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Sorry for the newbish question, but: Is it possible to use [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) to apply a "sepia" style filter, as well as append title cards to the beginning and end to a video?

I can't seem to find any tutorials that match this request, but I'm assuming it must be possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sepia you can try the `lut` filters or `colorchannelmixer` filter. See [these examples](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Examples-8).

To append a card at the beginning/end you have to concatenate. Three methods are available

- the demuxer
- protocol
- filter

With different types of files being concatenated (to put it simply) you are better off using the filter method. To combine the two filters (color effect and concatenate), you have to use `-filter_complex` and put the 2 filters in a chain.

For concatenate, [see this](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20%28join,%20merge%29%20media%20files).